# Django fixtures as a python script

Tags: python, django

Writing .json or .yaml for a lot of fixtures is tiresome (especially for Users password for example), just doing it in python with a nice `for` loop is really nice and fast.

But I can't find other people doing it like that.

- Is this a bad practice ?
- What's your way to do it ? .py in the fixtures/ directory, in a separate script/ directory  or as a management command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has internal command for preparing fixtures from database:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-app-label-app-label-app-label-model